# Count all elements of a certain name in an XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

Given the XML below:

```xml
<Items>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
</Items>
```

I am writing a function to return count of all `<Item>` elements (4 in this case). The actual XML file is huge and I don't want to load the entire thing in memory in order to parse it.

Using command line, I managed to get what I need with the following line:

```sh
grep "<Item>" my_file.xml -o | wc -l
```

Is there an equivalent solution in PHP that I can use to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easily done with XPath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('my_file.xml', LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$count = $xp->evaluate('count(//Item)');
```

The XPath expression returns the number of *all* `Item` tags in the document.

The `LIBXML_PARSEHUGE` option only affects internal limits on the depth, entity recursion, and the size of text nodes. However, the DOM parser *loads the entire document into memory*.

For really huge files, use a [SAX parser](http://php.net/xml), which operates on each piece of XML sequentially (and thus loads only a small portion of the document into memory):

```
$counter = 0;

$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, function ($parser, $name) use (&$counter) {
  if ($name === 'ITEM') {
    $counter++;
  }
}, null);

if (!($fp = fopen('my_file.xml', 'r'))) {
  die('Could not open XML input');
}

while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
  if (!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
    die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d",
      xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)),
      xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)));
  }
}
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
```

Comment: I ended up using `DOMDocument` for now. But SAX Parser is definitely a better option for huge files since it's an event-based parser rather than tree-based.